# Video Lectures on axiomatic Set Theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Are there any good online video Lectures for Axiomatic Set Theory? Maybe some that work with Kunen or Jech?

Comment: Do you have any university access of some sort?

Comment: Not yet, but this would help?

Comment: Well, some universities have resources available to them.